# Dynamo DB update syntax by just passing javascript object

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is there a simple way of updating multiple attributes just by passing the attribute as javascript object.
Update all object key value in the db, if `{a: 1, b: { c:1 } }`, just update attribute `a with 1`, attribute b with `{c:1}`

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-east-2" });

const PK = (userId) => `USER#${userId}`;
const SK = (file) => `FILE#${file}`;

const updateFn = async (tableName, { pk, sk }, attributes) => {
  const updateExpr = Object.keys(attributes)
    .map((key) => `${key} = :${key}`)
    .join(",");

  const exprAttVal = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(attributes).map(([key, val]) => [`:${key}`, val])
  );

  const params = {
    Key: { pk: PK(`${pk}`), sk: SK(`${sk}`) },
    UpdateExpression: "SET " + updateExpr,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: exprAttVal,
  };

  try {
    const records = await docClient
      .update({
        TableName: tableName,
        ...params,
      })
      .promise();
    console.log("records", records);
    return records;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error", err);
    return null;
  }
};

const TABLE_NAME = "FileTracker";

updateFn(
  TABLE_NAME,
  { pk: "pk", sk: "sk" },
  {
    score: 32,
    level: "1b2",
    foobar: "bla-bla",
  }
);
```

The above code will work for simple attributes like **`{a: 1}`** etc.

However if there is map like  **`{ stats:{ success: 1, failure: { reason: 'bla', count: 2} } }`**
the above code will not work since in update expression format should be of value **`SET stats.success = :stats.success, stats.failure.reason = :stats.failure.reason`**

**`ExpressionAttributeValues =  { ':stats.success': 2, 'stats.failure.reason': 'foo-reason' }`**

note `:stats.failure.reason` is not valid attribute value placeholder.

Just wanted to know if there is already code available for situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `flatten` your attributes before invoking `updateFn`.

Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flatten-javascript-objects-into-a-single-depth-object/) will help your to flatten an map object.